# Configuring bot without .bot file

Tags: botframework

Is there any way to configure a bot in the new Microsoft Bot Framework v4 without the .bot file?

I want to do this programatically and I cannot find this in the samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appsettings.json points to the bot file like this:

```
{
  "botFilePath": "BotConfiguration.bot",
  "botFileSecret": ""
}
```

then in the startup.cs this happens:

```
var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("botFileSecret")?.Value;
var botFilePath = Configuration.GetSection("botFilePath")?.Value;

// Loads .bot configuration file and adds a singleton that your Bot can access through dependency injection.
var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\BotConfiguration.bot", secretKey);
services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));

// Retrieve current endpoint.
var environment = _isProduction ? "production" : "development";
var service = botConfig.Services.Where(s => s.Type == "endpoint" && s.Name == environment).FirstOrDefault();
```

You will need to make changes to this if you wish to handle things without a .bot file.

Comment: Making changes to what? Do you mean `botConfig`? And where's that used?

Comment: As you are trying to make a custom solution for this and not use the built-in way of doing it, you are going to have to figure that part out.  Take a look at [`BotConfiguration`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/f21a38df65d044e0cdc2cdc76d3795f5249eeb7e/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Configuration/BotConfiguration.cs). This is where you need to put the values ultimately.  It then gets registered as a singleton `services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig);`